# How does Assembla compare to FogBugz + Kiln

Tags: project-management, software-as-a-service

I'm choosing a project management solution and narrowed it down to either [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) or [FogBugz + Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/pricing.html). These were my criteria:

- Hosted service but with an option to go to a custom installation (rules out e.g. [Codebase HQ](http://www.codebasehq.com/))
- Centered around projects, not repositories (GitHub, although having added some PM features recently, seems to be repo-centered)
- Git repository hosting a must, SVN + Mercurial nice to have
- Popular service with (at least somewhat) guaranteed continuity - both FogBugz and Assembla seem to be amongst the most popular PM solutions
- Wikis, discussions, code reviews, user management etc. The more features, the better. This rules out (otherwise a very nice service) BitBucket and others. Both FogBugz and Assembla seem quite feature packed.

I'm looking for someone who has experience with both FogBugz and Assembla and could compare them. This is what I've gathered so far from feature pages / screenshots / random mentions on the web:

- FogBugz seems to have quite a nice UX. Assembla makers are certainly trying hard and the screenshots don't look that bad but it still feels less elegant.
- FogBugz is offered with Kiln which I'm sure is a nice product but I'd prefer Git over Mercurial. I know FogBugz can be used with other SCM services but I'd rather have one integrated solution out of the box.
- Assembla is cheaper, actually much cheaper should there be more than a few users.

Maybe I'm wrong, these are just my first impressions. If someone could offer a more complete / educated comparison I would be grateful.

Comment: Why is gihub+trac/campfire/fogbugz/whatever_you_want bad?

Comment: Food for thought: FogBugz + Kiln was written by the same group of people who wrote the Stack Exchange sites. That might influence others here, and may even influence you.

Comment: @AntonBarkovsky It's not bad, I'm just looking for an integrated solution where all the services come in one "box".

Comment: 2 1/2 years later, I find myself with almost the exact same question.  Would you care to share your findings?

Answer (score 2):

I do not have experience with Fogbugz/Kiln so I can not directly answer the comparison question BUT I can say that Assembla is great. I have used it for a handful of projects and used both their Subversion and git which is nicely integrated their ticket and collaboration tools. It worked very well.

Comment: I finally had time to play with Assembla and while I was impressed with the feature list from the description, the UI / UX is so disappointing that I will probably look elsewhere. It's details but for example unreadable paragraphs because of their unlimited width is something I don't want to be dealing with.